# Python object attributes in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

In the following code, 2nd line throws an error 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find'. However, when I put it in the for loop it magically makes the very attribute available to me. Please help me understand what happens here.

```
results_user = con.find_all("table", {"id" : re.compile('post[0-9].*')})

results_user.find("td", class_= "alt2") # this throws and error

for name in results_user:
    nm = name.find_all("td", class_= "alt2")
    print(nm)
```

Comment: In the loop the object `name` is not the same as `results_user`, which is some sort of container.  `name` is an element of `results_user`.

Comment: You can call it on a string. By iterating with a for loop this is what you get. No magic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `find` is not the same as `find_all`
2. In the `for` loop you call the method `find_all` on each element inside `results_user`, not on `results_user` directly.

   It's the same as the difference between `['a', 'b', 'c'].upper()` (which doesn't work, `'list' object has no attribute 'upper'`) and `'a'.upper() ; 'b'.upper() ; 'c'.upper()`.

Comment: Thank you.  I got it now.                                                                                                                results_user[3].find_all("td", class_= "alt2")

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that same for loop you have shown there. You are accessing two different objects. "results_user" and "name" are two different types of things. The former doesn't have a "find" attribute, as indicated by the error.